# Easiest fix for polygon corner error in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, error, intersect

I am new to QGIS. What would be the easiest way to fix this apparent boundary error in a shapefile that I have downloaded?

I believe it was intended for these lines to intersect as a 4-way corner, but something apparently went wrong in the boundary drawing.

When I attempt to use this layer as input for an intersect, I get an 'invalid geometry' error for this feature. Am I correct in assuming this corner problem might be the basis of the intersect error?

[image: Error in boundary lines. Corner intersection jagged.]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  Are you sure it's incorrect?  After looking at boundaries for years I've come to realise a lot of instances like yours that may look odd or incorrect are actually correct in the real world.  I'd be cautious about correcting errors in boundary information until I am certain they are actually errors.

Comment: a useful tool is the processing toolbox algorithm - check validity which will helpfully show you the invalid geometries and indicate why they are invalid

Answer (score 2):

For future reference: knowing your operating system/ QGIS version etc. would be helpful, but I'll give it a shot.

- As already mentioned, the "[Topology checker plugin"](http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_topology_checker.html) or the "[check geometries tool](http://www.northrivergeographic.com/archives/qgis-2-12-check-geometries-plugin)" can be very useful for this kind of shapefile-trouble. However, in this specific case I didn't find the result very helpful. Instead I would suggest (QGIS 2.14.10) running the "[v.clean-Algorithm (Grass)](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/v.clean.html)" twice. Once with the "snap" cleaning tool and afterwards with the "break" tool. That should (hopefully) fix your problem automatically (see screenshots).
- An other option with more control over the end result would be to just edit the layer manually and define snapping-options (Settings --> Snapping Options), you can edit each node separately and also add new nodes. This gives you the maximum of control for the way, your polygons / lines connect. If you have a huge dataset that is in this condition, I would not recommend that though. Also depends on how accurate your final map or findings have to be.

**Screenshots:**

1) Initial state:

[image]

2) v.clean toolset and how to find it: click!

[image]

3) snap! - ui. (keeping the default parameters is fine)

[image]

4) Output

[image]

5) Repeat previous steps, just choose break with default parameters instead: voila! - since I just had 3 polygons this is the result.

[image]

Since you had a zoomed in version of your data I could probably not fully recreate your conditions, but let me know, if it worked. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The comment by @Midavalo regarding changing the boundary is very good advice.
If you are able, get legal descriptions of the parcels.
If you find the lines of your drawing do not match, then you may edit the lines accordingly (and cautiously), but I would save the layer to another name before doing so.
You could make edits to the geometry creating a four way corner that could be very erroneous.
If area calculations, or payment calculations are made using the area you edited, and the edits you make are incorrect, you could be held responsible.

The topology checker may not flag that portion of the parcel as invalid.

I would be very cautious about editing original data without evidence to support your decision to do so.